# Относительный путь

Tags: css, веб-программирование, отладка

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с проблемой не отображения картинки. Картинка задана через *.css*
Структура папок такова:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Путь к файлу задаю следующим образом:
(`)background-image: url('../images/mag.svg');(`)
Но по какой-то причине файлик упорно ищется в папке *css*, а не уровнем выше. Почему так происходит? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если посмотреть в результирующий html, то какой там путь?

Comment: Так, варианты: 1). Одну точку вместо двух написали где-то в путях (скорее всего) 2). в цсс у вас вложенные папки и из вложенной папки вы лезете вверх 3). У вас стили как-то процессятся неправильно (это если этап сборки стилей есть, но вроде нету)

Comment: В результатирующем html показывает url('/images/mag.svg'), то есть пропущены 2 точки.
1. Исключено, проверялось, и запускалось на локалке.
2. Исключено, у меня 1 css. Никаких вложенных папок там нет.

Comment: попробуйте поменять кавычки на " или \' - может ваша cms пакостит...

Comment: абсолютный путь пробовали? работает?

Comment: Cms не юзаю. Кавычки и абсолютный путь пробовал - не работает. Что самое забавное, какой бы путь в коде не писал, в стилях в итоге задан этот путь - url('/images/mag.svg'), то есть ошибочный. Не понимаю, что присходит.

Comment: а где jquery сидит?

Comment: @Святослав, ок, тогда очевидно либо Вы подключаете не тот стилевой файл/не ту хтмл/не тот проект. Либо кеш браузера

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму так ошибка в JS

Comment: Ошибка обнаружилась. Все - таки кеш браузера. Спасибо всем, особенно Утке! =)

Comment: @L.Vadim ошибка 404 http ошибка "нет такой штуки", js тут только ее показывает

Comment: @Святослав расписал в ответе что обычно делают с кешем чтобы не напрягал

Comment: Достаточно обширный ответ. Огромное спасибо. PrtSc и в рамочку! :)

Answer (score 1):

Исследование в комментариях выяснило что виноват кеш браузера.

Кеш можно чистить вручную, обычные шорткаты такие:
1. **Ctrl** + **F5** - перезагрузка страницы без кеша
2. **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Delete** - выбрать "кеш".

Для целей разработки в Chrome Dev Tools (и вероятно в аналогичных инструментах других браузеров) есть настройка:
**F12** - открываем devtools
Три точки справа сверху devtools (меню "**Customize and control devtools**") - **Settings**
Слева таб **Preferences**
Группа **Networks**
Галка **Disable cache (while DevTools is open)**

Это все для целей разработки, если нам нужно чтобы файл не кешировался для конечного юзера, обычно выставляют правильные http-заголовки и дописывают новые гет параметры к запросу ресурса, но это уже отдельная долгая история.